# prevent update using validate

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have `User` model which contains field `type` which is `enum ('client','agent')`.
After I register user I don't want this field to be updated ever - I am looking for some validation method in model which always returns false - then I can add rule on update which will always fail on this field.

I know I could add custom validation rule but maybe there is better (core/build in) method in Cake?

In fact there are many fields I don't want to update like username for example - how I can handle this in Cake? Because I am afraid that some1 my contruct his own Form where he will post for example 'username' and it will be updated...

Answer (score 1):

If your worried about someone posting via mass assignment or CSRF, you can enable the [Security Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html). Provided you build your forms using the FormHelper you will be protected.

Comment: you can also use whitelisting on forms - read some more about it  atwww.dereuromark.de/2010/09/21/saving-model-data-and-security/